# How to find all the substrings in a .txt file in Python

Tags: python, file, text, substring

Okay, so I have this text file:

```
         hello there hello print hello there print lolol
```

this is what I want to do in Python(down below in pseudo-code):

```
         when print statement found:
              print next five letters(not including space);
```

This is the result I want:

```
         >>>[hello, lolol]
```

How do I solve this problem in python?

Comment: what would the output be for the input `"hello to my friend"`, that is, there is no next 5 contiguous letters. would the output have to be `["hello", "tomyf"]`

Comment: Sorry, I miswrote my comment. I meant to ask: what would the output be for the input `"print to my friend"`, that is, there is no next 5 contiguous letters after print. would the output have to be `["tomyf"]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are always 5 letters that follow a `print` and a space, you can use the following regex with lookbehind:

```
import re
print(re.findall(r'(?<=\bprint ).{5}', 'hello there hello print hello there print lolol'))
```

This outputs:

```
['hello', 'lolol']
```

Answer (score 1):

`split` by `'print '` and use list indexing to get the first 5 characters of the string

```
In [253]: [res[:5] for res in s.split('print ')[1:]]
Out[253]: ['hello', 'lolol']
```

Comment: yes, that works. i am not sure, but does s mean the text file?

Comment: `s` is the string that you will be performing the operation on. can be a text file or an html doc

Comment: i don't know what you mean

Comment: like, for res in s.split('print ')[1:]: print(res[:5]) maybe

Comment: you will have to elaborate. i don't know what you mean by "extended format"

Comment: instead of using a shortened list comprehension, show how to do this with for loops.

Comment: you are compressing the for loop into one line. I want you to show me how this looks line in many lines